# Getting Message time out exception while executing Spring batch job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

The below error is coming while executing the batch job:

org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timeout occurred before all partitions returned

What would be the possible reasons behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I see this error when the manager and worker step jobs are not configured as required. So the worker might be getting the partitions and processing them but not able to connect with the manager. So the manager waits for the missed partition and fails with the timeout exception